# RxJS and HTML Geolocation API Return POSITION_UNAVAILABLE After First Location Update

Tags: rxjs, geolocation, gps, rxjs-observables

I'm attempting to observe a user's current geolocation. I'm using the Google Chrome browser and altering the location in the developer tools for debugging purposes.
I don't have an SSL connection, so I added my URL to the "Insecure origins treated as secure" section at chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure.
I've granted permissions and I get the initial location once the permission is given.

However, as soon as I set a new location, the API throws a POSITION_UNAVAILABLE error and I don't understand why.
My current workaround is to check for either POSITION_UNAVAILABLE or TIMEOUT and try again, but this approach doesn't feel correct.
I also experimented with a custom React hook where I didn't encounter this issue. I'm new to RxJS and I'm unsure if I'm making a mistake.

RxJS Version 7.8.1

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {action, observable} from 'mobx';

export default class GeoLocationState {
    public static createState() {
        return new GeoLocationState(state);
    }

    public readonly locationWatcher$: Observable<GPSPosition>;

    private constructor() {
        this.locationWatcher$ = new Observable<GPSPosition>((observer) => {
            const onSuccess: PositionCallback = (position) => {
                observer.next({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                    accuracy: position.coords.accuracy,
                    speed: position.coords.speed,
                    heading: position.coords.heading,
                    timeStamp: position.timestamp,
                    altitude: position.coords.altitude,
                    altitudeAccuracy: position.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
                });
            };
            const onError: PositionErrorCallback = (error) => {
                observer.error(error);
            };

            const watcherId = window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                maximumAge: 500,
            });

            return () => {
                window.navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watcherId);
            };
        });
    }
}

export interface GPSPosition {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;

    accuracy: number;
    timeStamp: number;
    altitude: number | null;
    speed: number | null;
    heading: number | null;
    altitudeAccuracy: number | null;
}
```

Subscription

```
const watchLocationSubscription = state.getState(GeoLocationState).locationWatcher$
.pipe(
    catchError((error: GeolocationPositionError) => {
        if (error.code === 2 || error.code === 3) {
            return of(null);
        } else {
            return throwError(error);
        }
    }),
    repeat(),
)
.subscribe({
    next: (position) => {
        ...
    },
    error: (error) => {
        ...
    },
});
```

Comment: I don't necessarily see anything wrong with the RxJS part. How do you set the location from console?

Comment: I’m using some predefined locations, such as London and Shanghai. I also added a custom location. I just select one: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/settings/locations/